# При пуше не появляется ветка на гитхабе

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Сделал форк, клонировал репозиторий, создал ветку, теперь когда делаю `git push` на гитХабе, ветка не появляется.

Но после того как сделал `git push --all` появилась.

Так и должно быть?

Comment: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.ru.html Почитайте :)

Comment: Наверное, вы делали пуш другой ветки? Указывайте явно `git push origin/branch_name`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

создавать ветки можно и разными командами и с разными опциями, передаваемыми командам (ещё и нектороые конфигурационные опции влияют на этот процесс. см. `man git-config`).

1. если вы создавали ветку командой `branch`:

   ```
   $ git branch новая-ветка
   ```

   то вы не переключились на эту ветку, текущей веткой осталась та, что и была до выполнения этой команды. соответственно, командой `push` (без дополнительных опций/аргументов) вы пытались отправить изменения из текущей ветки, которая, скорее всего, уже имеется в удалённом репозитории.
2. если вы создавали ветку командой `checkout` с опцией `-b`:

   ```
   $ git checkout -b новая-ветка
   ```

   то переключение на новую ветку должно было произойти. но в этом случае команда `push` (без доп. опций/аргументов) должна была вернуть ошибку вида:

   ```
   $ git push
   fatal: The current branch новая-ветка has no upstream branch.
   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

       git push --set-upstream origin новая-ветка
   ```

   т.е., потребовалась бы указание дополнительной опции (подсказана прямо в сообщении об ошибке) для привязки новой ветки к одноимённой ветке в удалённом репозитории.

когда же вы выполнили команду `push` с опцией `--all`, то, независимо от того, какая ветка была в этот момент текущей, программа *git* попыталась создать все недостающие в удалённом репозитории ветки и отправить в них локальные изменения. но недостающие привязки (см. пункт 2 выше) в этом случае программа *git* не создаст: их надо создавать вручную, чтобы впоследстии можно было из новой ветки выполнять команду `push` без дополнительных опций/аргументов.

Answer (score 1):

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.ru.html

Создать новую ветку с названием `"feature_x"` и переключиться на неё можно командой

```
git checkout -b feature_x
```

переключиться обратно на master

```
git checkout master
```

удалить ветку

```
git branch -d feature_x
```

**ветка не будет доступна тем, кто пользуется с вами удаленным репозиторием пока вы не отправите её туда
    `git push origin <имя_ветки>`**